# Getting improper response for Json webservice

Tags: android, json, httpresponse, okhttp

I am using okhttp library for Json parsing.

I have created my AsyncTask as below for my Login Webservice :

```
class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String mstrLoginResponse="";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("mobile_number", strPhone)
                    .add("password", strPassword)
                    .build();
            mstrLoginResponse = HttpUtils.postRun("login", formBody);
            Constant.displayLogE(">>>TT : ",""+mstrLoginResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (mstrLoginResponse != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonRegister = new JSONObject(mstrLoginResponse);

                int strLoginStatus = jsonRegister.getInt("status");
                String strMessage = jsonRegister.getString("message");
                if (strLoginStatus == 1) {
                    JSONObject jsonUserId = jsonRegister.getJSONObject("data");
                    String strUserId = jsonUserId.getString("user_id");
                    AppSettings.setPref(SignInActivity.this, USER_ID, String.valueOf(strUserId));
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    Constant.displayToast(SignInActivity.this, "" + strMessage);
                } else {
                    ApiUtils.showAlertDialogue(SignInActivity.this, "" + strMessage);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, Unfortunetly getting below response :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                                                 <html lang="en">
                                                 <head>
                                                 <meta charset="utf-8">
                                                 <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
                                                 <style type="text/css">

                                                 ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
                                                 ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
```

and Exeption : `org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-24 00:41:03.314 349-349/com.roadysmart W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)`

I am getting proper response in Postman. 
My HttpUtils class is as below : `

```
    public class HttpUtils {
    /*public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");*/
  public static String BASE_URL = "http://temp.in/projects/temp/";

    public static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public static String getRun(String url) throws IOException {
        Log.d("URL===>", url);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

    public static String postRun(String type, RequestBody formBody) throws IOException {
        String str = "";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BASE_URL)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

}
```

What might be the mistake ? Please, Help .

===>>EDIT :

Getting Proper response in postman as below :

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Login successful",
"data": {
    "name": "subhu",
    "mobile_number": "7777777777",
    "email": "bhargavmodi777@gmail.com",
    "user_id": "20"
}
```

}

Comment: What data type is the server expecting on the POST? You sure it isn't JSON instead of FormBody?

Comment: ya am sending formbody to my post request..

Comment: it's the same url you used in postman and your AsyncTask ?

Comment: yes sir, am using the same..

Comment: You added the postman response. Which only tells me that your endpoint responds with `application/json`. What parameters are you sending? what URL are you calling? The code you are executing from your phone is it on LTE/3G network or on your WIFI/ETHERNET connection... Check my updated answer please.

Comment: Dayan sir, done : When i used whole url instead of seperating it to BASEURL and special one. Thanks for your efforts for helping me out.

Comment: @ZaptechDevKumar Glad you got it working, please accept the answer if it helped you resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your response - `<title>404 Page Not Found</title>` tells me that your endpoint doesn't exist because you entered it incorrectly or the server is simply not running.

That exception you posted relates to the same issue, it can't parse the JSON because what the web call received was not `application/json` and instead just raw HTML.

```
Exeption : org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot
```

With that said, `public static String BASE_URL = "http://temp.in/projects/temp/";` looks like a bad URL. Here is what I recommend:

1. First manually load that URL in your browser, you will notice the same HTML your client call received, will be presented to you.
2. Make sure you are running your server/service or whatever it is that responds to your request. You say Postman works, what parameters did you use? What are you communicating with?
3. If PostMan works, and postman runs from your computer, your computer is connected to your local network I presume. Is your Android device on the local network as well? Or are you on cell service (3G/LTE). If you are then your endpoint can't be reached unless you are connected to a VPN or something.

Comment: let me add postman response..pls. check after a miniute.. i am editing..